# reading comma separated text files of different lengths in java

Tags: java

so I have a text file and i am trying to read line by line and then populate my array list.
a sample text file is shown below:

```
10,11,11/10/2021,24,1,2
11,12,11/10/2021,1,2,3
12,13,11/10/2021,24,5
13,14,11/10/2021,1,11,32,2
14,15,11/10/2021,1,9,8
```

I have been able to read in the first 4 elements (ID,ID,date,price)
and then i need to populate the other elements on that line into an array list (all elements after price)

the problem I am having is that it populates all the other lines into the array list and just not the remaining elements for the one line.

here is the code

```
    int ID = 0;
    int spareID = 0;
    String date = "";
    float fee = 0;
    ArrayList<String> limits = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Import> imports= new ArrayList<Imports>();
 File myfile = new File("file.txt");
    try {
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myfile);

      inputFile.useDelimiter(",");
      // setting comma as delimiter pattern
      while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
        ID = inputFile.nextInt();
        SpareID = inputFile.nextInt();
        date = inputFile.next();
        fee = inputFile.nextFloat();
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
          limits.add(inputFile.next());
        }
          Import import = new Import(ID, spareID, fee, date, limits);
          imports.add(import);
        
      }
      inputFile.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("error: can not find file");
    }
```

the array list is capturing the rest of the text file when i need it to capture just the remaining elements on that line.

Edit: the first 4 elements of the line will all go into a  different variable and then I need the rest or the elements on that line only to go into the array list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Scanner.nextLine()` to get a single line, then create a second `Scanner` with that line to parse it contents.

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myfile);
while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
    Scanner line = new Scanner(inputFile.nextLine());
    // setting comma as delimiter pattern
    line.useDelimiter(",");
    ID = line.nextInt();
    SpareID = line.nextInt();
    date = line.next();
    fee = line.nextFloat();
    while (line.hasNext()) {
        limits.add(line.next());
    }
}
inputFile.close();
```

Comment: sorry, this just adds the last line of the text file only

Comment: nevermind, your code was correct i had another error thankyou!